# How to disable error tooltips on admin forms

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

How can I disable error tooltips on forms that are generated by Sonata Admin bundle? I'd rather show errors below fields instead of tooltips.

These error messages are rendered inline by the Sonata, but then some JavaScript code removes them from DOM and changes into dynamic tooltips.

Is there a configuration option to disable this behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure you are running in Prod environment? check your config

Comment: @AndrewAtkinson environments has nothing to do with this. It's a feature built into Sonata Admin bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a javascript code that overrides Sonata admin functionality

For example:

```
var Admin = Admin || {};

// disable popover error messages
Admin.add_pretty_errors = function(){};
```

Comment: I don't like this solution (it's more like workaround) but it works and I don't have to rewrite Sonata's code. It's a good temporary solution until proper one is implemented. There is option to disable/enable `select2` so this one should be configurable too.

Answer (score 1):

Sonata Admin now has an option for this, however it works on all forms at once.

The following is the YAML config equivalent to disable HTML5 validation:

```
sonata_admin:
    options:
        html5_validate: false
```

Comment: See also: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

are you referring to the HTML5 validation tooltips?  Most modern browsers have built in validation for certain validation rules (such as 'required') Read the [HTML5 validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-validation) tip in the docs.

Basically, when rendering the form, you need to add the `novalidate` attribute to the form. This is from the docs:

```
{{ form(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
```

You can adapt that to fit your use case.

Comment: I'm talking about Sonata Admin bundle. I'm not rendering the forms myself. This is a feature of Sonata Admin bundle - it adds a jQuery code that turns error `div`s into tooltips. I'm looking for an option to disable this feature.

Comment: @SiliconMind: You can override the template "base_edit_form.html.twig" in your admin bundle and add the novalidate attribute in the form tag